# How to install facebook pop manually?

Tags: ios, facebook-pop

I want to use facebook pop, but I don't know how to embed it into my project. My project isn't workspace and no cocoapods, I just want to add them directly. Anybody help?

Comment: There's a header on [the README](https://github.com/facebook/pop/blob/master/README.md#non-cocoapods-installation) called "Non-CocoaPods Installation", is that not what you want?

Comment: my project c++ standard library is libstdc++(GNU c++ standard library), if I change it to (LLVM c++ standard library with c++11 support), there'll be a lot of error warning......

Comment: I have seen it, but I don't know how to add pop.framework. The most important thing is that I don't want to add the project into my project, I just want to add the pop folder into my project, sorry I'm a fresher for this thing....

Comment: pop must use LLVM c++ standard library with c++11 support?

Answer (score 2):

I just did this, so here are stepwise instructions. (Basically, expanding on the [README](https://github.com/facebook/pop/blob/master/README.md#ios-8-embedded-framework) which says: `"By adding the project to your project and adding pop.embedded framework to the Embedded Binaries section on the General tab of your app's target, you can set up pop in seconds!"`)

1. Clone the library into a directory accessible from your app's project:

   `git clone https://github.com/facebook/pop.git`
2. Open a Finder window into the newly cloned `pop` directory.
3. Drag the `pop.xcodeproj` file into your app's project navigator, inside your app's `.xcodeproj`.

[image: add pop project to your app's]

4. Go to your app's project, select your target, select the `General` tab:

[image: Project / Target / General]

5. Under `Embedded Binaries`, add the Facebook pop framework. There are two on the list, one for iOS, the other for OS X. Because Xcode, the names are undifferentiated.

[image: select Facebook pop framework]

- Verify you selected the correct one by looking at the path in the `Embedded Binaries` section after adding it.

[image: it says 'iphoneos']

6. Use the `pop` framework by adding an `@import pop;` to whatever view controller you want to use it in.

Comment: ah, sorry. Looks like Pop is only compatible with iOS 7.0 and higher.

Comment: Btw, I did run into problems with installing it this way. Seemingly randomly, the project would fail to compile and then raise errors that were previously not there. I fixed this by deleting the framework, then reinstalling, but this got to be too much of a pain. I tried installing via `cocoapods`, so far no troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the tremendous help, Anthony! Was never able to import any framework as easily as I did this one just be following your steps. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

"... manually copy the files under the pop subdirectory into your project. If installing manually, ensure the C++ standard library is also linked by including `-lc++` to your project linker flags."

Do you see that introduction?

Comment: There is a lot of problems, not just what u say.  My project is big now and it use the old c++ lib. If I change it there will be a lot of warnning......So the problem is the c++ lib, POP using the new one, but compiler is using the old one, I can't change them....

Comment: @KevinWLC Maybe you can open a issue on pop and introduce your problem. Sorry I cannot give you help.